# Multiple counts in the same sql request in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a new developer in Spark Scala and I have a simple table like this :

```
City     Dept   employee_id   employee_salary
NY       FI     10            10000
NY       FI     null          20000
WDC      IT     30            100000    
LA       IT     40            500
```

What I want to do is to calculate :

- the number of employees by city & department (a simple count(*))
- the number of employees with a non null id
- the number of employees with a small (< 500) or medium (< 1000) or high salary (> 1000) => 3 additional counts !

So, as an output, I should have something like this :

```
City     Dept   total_emp   total_emp   total_emp_small  total_emp_medium  total_emp_high 
NY       FI     100         90         10                70               10 
WDC      IT     200         100    
LA       IT     10          10
```

The challenge here is that I want to optimize those counts. Because as you can see, we have here many counts to do. Without an optimisation the brute force for me is to do one count by request and generate a new DF result after each count and at the end I do a left joint based on the fixed column (city & dept) to add those new columns. But it will be too heavy since my table contains a lot of data.

I think that the method "window" can simplify this but I am not sure.

Can you help me this at least with just 2 cases (id != null and salary < 500).

Thank you in advance

Comment: what should be expected output dataframe as per your sample input data, can you please provide i t

Comment: @Nikk Done. I added an example of the output that I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scala> df.show
+----+----+-----------+---------------+
|City|Dept|employee_id|employee_salary|
+----+----+-----------+---------------+
|  NY|  FI|         10|          10000|
|  NY|  FI|       null|          20000|
| WDC|  IT|         30|         100000|
|  LA|  IT|         40|            500|
|  LA|  IT|         40|            600|
|  LA|  IT|       null|            200|
+----+----+-----------+---------------+


scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("NonNullEmpID", when(col("employee_id").isNotNull, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)))
                   .withColumn("Salary_Cat", 
                               when(col("employee_salary") < 500, lit("SmallSalary")).
                               when(col("employee_salary") < 1000, lit("MediumSalary")).
                               when(col("employee_salary") >= 1000, lit("HighSalary")))

scala> val SalaryMap = df1.groupBy("Salary_Cat").agg(count(lit(1)).alias("count")).collect.flatMap(x => Map(x(0).toString -> x.toSeq.slice(1, x.length).mkString)).toMap

//the number of employees by city & department (a simple count(*))
//the number of employees with a non null id
//the number of employees with a small (< 500) or medium (< 1000) or high salary (> 1000) => 3 additional counts !

scala> df1.groupBy("City", "Dept")
          .agg(count(lit(1)).alias("#Emp_per_City_Dept"), sum(col("NonNullEmpID")).alias("NonNullEmpID"))
          .withColumn("total_emp_small", lit(SalaryMap("SmallSalary")))
          .withColumn("total_emp_medium", lit(SalaryMap("MediumSalary")))
          .withColumn("total_emp_high", lit(SalaryMap("HighSalary")))
          .show()
+----+----+------------------+------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
|City|Dept|#Emp_per_City_Dept|NonNullEmpID|total_emp_small|total_emp_medium|total_emp_high|
+----+----+------------------+------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
|  NY|  FI|                 2|           1|              1|               2|             3|
|  LA|  IT|                 3|           2|              1|               2|             3|
| WDC|  IT|                 1|           1|              1|               2|             3|
+----+----+------------------+------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I see your point but it's not really what I want as an output (you can see please my new edited message : I added the ouput that I want). In fact, I DON'T want to display the employee_id. The id are juste useful here to do the counts that's all !

Comment: @salamanka44 please check now,  I have updated my answer. As per your requirement, you do not need to use Window and Join in code. above code will be optimised .